# Values after decimal point not coming while exporting if it's zero

Tags: angularjs, excel, csv, angular-ui-grid

`angular-ui-grid` version `v3.0.0-rc.22-e8fe073`

I am using `angularjs` currency filter with my custom filter. Please find below filter definition:

```
HelperServices.filter('customCurrencyFormat',function($filter){
    return function(val, cond , decimalPlaces){

        if(typeof decimalPlaces =='undefined' || decimalPlaces ==null ){
            decimalPlaces = 2;
        }

        if(val == "0" && cond == "showZero"){
            return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces));
        }else if(val == 0 && cond == "hideZero"){
            return null;
        }else{
            if(val < 0){
                return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces)).replace("(", "-").replace(")", "");
            }else{              
                return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And in a grid definition filter is applied as `cellFilter: 'customCurrencyFormat:""'`. The filter works properly on a grid. It displays as per the definition.

Now, in export the definition is as below:

```
exporterFieldCallback: function(grid, row, col, input ) {               
                if(col.name == 'nameofcolumn'){
                    return $filter('customCurrencyFormat')(input, '', 2);
                } 
            }
```

When I open csv file in `MS Excel`, the single digit values are coming without decimal points. Even I checked what filter actually returns on console. And found that filter returns even single digit value with decimal point.

Like, value 2 should be exported in csv as 2.00 and should display it as 2.00 as well.

**Why the values of a grid are not exporting with decimal point in csv format ? How do I display all values with decimal point as it is written in my filter definition ?**

Comment: @pnuts - If I format cell as number or currency, the value comes with '.00'.

Comment: @pnuts - allowing Excel to use number format as default is not possible for me. How do I export the value as same as it is visible in a grid on webpage ?

Comment: @pnuts - even passing the value as string type from grid does not solve the issue.